# how to force geom_smooth render for ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to force render a smoother line for this multi-group plot, even in situations where a group has only one or two values. see below:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(group = factor(c(rep("A",3),rep("B",2),"C")), x = c(1,2,3,1,2,2), value = runif(6))
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=value,group=group,color=group))+
  geom_point(size=2)+
  geom_line(stat="smooth",method = "loess",size = 2, alpha = 0.3)
```

[image]

Here's The output I want to see:

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what the expected output is, especially when a group has only one value. In the case of two values, you can use `method = "lm"` as there is no need for anything smoother than a straight line. In the case of, say, 3 points, the problem isn't about "forcing"; the problem is that `loess` is unable to fit a smooth line out of so few points. Something other than `loess` is needed then. Now if what you mean is to plot a smooth curve for the *whole range of `x` for each group*, then the problem is even more undefined.

Comment: if all groups have three or more points then the smoother will render.  However, since the loess applies to each group independently, there should be a way to render it for groups with 3 or more points even of other groups have 2 or one points.  my expected output is for ggplot to draw a loess smoother for group "A"  only.  I can force this by excluding group A and B from the data (df[df$group=="A"]) but that's not what I want.

Comment: Ok, that makes the question clear, I suggest to update your post accordingly as well.

Comment: It seems like you solved it? Maybe a cleaner version would be to plot the points first and then send a filtered version of the data set to the `geom_line` portion.

Comment: seems like a cumbersome approach.  1.  filter all group >=3, render "loess" smoother.  2.  filter all groups==2, render line, 3.  filter all groups==1, render points. 4. combine plots.   I was hoping to help ggplot ignore the singularities and render for valid groups in a single step but maybe it's a no go!

Comment: IMHO, I am not sure if a loess model (or: *any* statistical model) is the right approach for so small samples anyways and I think this approach is fairly straight forward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The call gives a lot of warnings which can be inspected by `warnings()`. One of the warnings says "*zero-width neighborhood. make span bigger*".

So, I tried OP's code with the additional `span = 1` parameter:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = value, group = group, color = group)) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  geom_line(
    stat = "smooth",
    method = "loess",
    span = 1,
    size = 2,
    alpha = 0.3
  )
```

and got smoothed curves for groups A and B with only 3 and 2 data points, resp.

[image]

Comment: It's exactly what I needed.  Much more elegant solution!  thanks!