# Cannot seem to plot three columns

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a datset, which I want to plot:

> Percentage_low_income / Distance / City
>
> 50.8 /5/ Amsterdam
> 50.9 /10/ Amsterdam
> 45.5 /Municipality/ Amsterdam
> 53.1 /5 / Rotterdam
> 53.1 /10/ Rotterdam 39 /Municipality/ Rotterdam
> 51.6 5 The_Hague
> 50.1 10 The_Hague
> 36.7 Municipality The_Hague
> 48.1 5 Utrecht 48 10 Utrecht
> 40.5 Municipality Utrecht
> 50.6 5 Total
> 50.5 10 Total 40 Municipality Total

I want to have the Distance on the x-axis, the percentage on the y-axis and the cities as colour. But, to increase the readability of the graph I also want to include smooth lines that go through all three points per city. My code:

```
ggplot(data = dat, mapping = aes(x = Distance, y =
Percentage_low_income, color = City)) + geom_point() +
geom_smooth(method = "auto", se = FALSE)
```

However, it only plots the data points, with different colours for the cities, but it does not seem to plot the smooth lines, can anyone help me out?

Comment: Could you please `dput()` your data.

Comment: I strongly suspect you've got too few data points. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54008014/how-to-force-geom-smooth-render-for-ggplot

Comment: (which also means what you're doing is at the least questionable). If you want to show change, you could just use geom_line instead for example, or if you want smooth curves, you could also smoothen with splines