# Plotting 3 different scatter values in a single graph using method= 'gam' [ggplot2]

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting the relationship between employment share of industry and log GDP per Capita for 3 years- 1991, 2001, and 2011.

I am trying to use method='gam'to get three different curves. However, my code is giving me a single curve. My code:

```
  ggplot(df, aes(x=log(gdp_pc_ppp), y=ind_emp_sh, color = year)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = 'gam', se = FALSE)
```

Sample of data:

```
structure(list(year = structure(c(1991, 2001, 2011, 1991, 2001, 
2011), label = "Time", format.stata = "%10.0g"), ind_emp_sh = structure(c(NA, 
NA, NA, 0.000993891337029564, 0.000888750150546182, 0.000914258292239977
), label = "Employment in industry (% of total employment) (modeled ILO estimate) [SL.IND.EM", format.stata = "%10.0g"), 
    gdp_pc_ppp = structure(c(38455.2077682848, 39388.3526308389, 
    35392.605185777, 3071.03916046043, 2994.43035908696, 3617.85449070659
    ), label = "GDP per capita, PPP (constant 2017 international $) [NY.GDP.PCAP.PP.KD]", format.stata = "%10.0g")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Even the color scheme is appearing wrong. Can anyone guide me as to where I am going wrong?

Comment: very possibly too few data points? e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54008014/how-to-force-geom-smooth-render-for-ggplot

Comment: In the sample data, you only have one non-NA point for each year, so we don't get any `geom_smooth` lines when we try to plot. You might want to consider turning `year` into a factor if you want to use it as a grouping variable though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample is too small to fit a gam to, so using some alternative fake data:

```
set.seed(0)
df <- data.frame(year = sample(c(1991,2001,2011), 100, TRUE), 
                 ind_emp_sh=runif(100), 
                 gdp_pc_ppp = rlnorm(100))
```

you now need to specify that `year` is a grouping variable with either:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=log(gdp_pc_ppp), y=ind_emp_sh, color = year, group=year)) + 
geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = 'gam', se = FALSE)
```

[image: Output 1]

or

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=log(gdp_pc_ppp), y=ind_emp_sh, color = factor(year))) + 
geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = 'gam', se = FALSE)
```

[image: Output 2]

The second method has the advantage of making using the default colours for a factor rather than continuous variable, so they're easier to see apart.